# Altas layer create fake initial message

Tags: ios, chat, layerkit

I use Atlas Layer to make a chat between an app user on one side and a support user on another side. Everything works great. But I need to have a welcome message from support side when user starts to chat for the first time. And I don't understand is it possible?
I looked Atlas demo code with mock objects as `LYRClientMock`, `LYRConversationMock` etc, and I tried to use them to built my welcome message. But all this stuff work in its mock-space.

So, I have an `ATLConversationViewController` subclass, where I create a conversation with support and I want to see an additional message at the top of conversation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have contacted with Atlas support. They told me about announcements, which are available via Layer API, not Atlas iOS SDK.

> ```
> If this is a one-way message that can't be replied to, you should consider using Announcements:
> https://developer.layer.com/docs/platform/messages#send-an-announcement
> ```